# Why does my AJAX request receive null responseText

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, servlets

I'm sending a request to a Java servlet using a Javascript function, and the servlet writes a response with content type set to "text/plain".
I've traced this through with Firebug, and request.responseText is always null, even though the request completes with status 200 (OK).
Why is responseText null?

I have previously tried this with a Java client, which did successfully receive the response.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("POST", <MY URL>, true);
    request.onreadystatechange = function() {
       if (request.readyState == 4) {
                var resp = request.responseText;
                console.log(resp);
        }
    }

    request.send(null);
  });
```

**UPDATE**:

Following suggestions in the answer given, I used Chrome, and viewing the Javascript console I noticed the following error

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/... Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

In my server code I used the following to set the appropriate header in the HTTP response

```
setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
```

And voila - 42K of data returned as expected in the response!

Comment: I don't see enough information here to go on. What browser? What's the response text sent? etc... You may wish to use an AJAX abstraction.

Comment: What if you use an actual string in the argument for your `send()` method, instead of `null`? I wouldn't think it'd have to be anything particularly meaningful, but perhaps your server-side script is looking for a POST variable it's not getting. Just a thought.

Comment: Can you show your Java code? (Also, you probably should test the status as well as the readyState.)

Comment: try to run the URL as normal HTTP request in browser, If you don't get any response debug the Java(servlet) Code

Comment: My Java code is actually a Wicket component (still boils down to a servlet though). I could post the code, but as it does work with a standalone Java client, and I get a valid response when pasting the URL into the browser, I thought the problem was with my Javascript.

Comment: Be aware of XDR request. Take care the URL you are requesting is in the same domain of the page loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which browser are you using?
Try with chrome and see network and console output.

I have similar headaches due the fact I was doing XDR requests. On FF all seems right and a 200 code is returned but with chrome you have more information and will see a 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error.

On your server side try to set the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" to allow request from any source page.

Comment: Both the client and server are local. But I'll try the test with Chrome and see what happens.

Comment: Spot on! SO does it again. Thanks!!

Comment: There are different ways to make XDR request, no matter if in the same local server.